# Dispatcher.InvokeAsync in F#

Tags: wpf, f#, task-parallel-library, dispatcher

I can't understand how to translate this code to f#:

```
var x = await Application.Current.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(c);

// the type of c is Func<int>
```

If I try to do this

```
let x = Async.AwaitTask(Application.Current.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(c))
```

I have a compiler error:

```
Threading.DispatcherOperation<int> is not compatible with Task<int>
```

How to do it?

Comment: What is the type of `InvokeAsync`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as I can see [DispatcherOperation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcheroperation(v=vs.110).aspx) is awaitable and F# compiler does not support working with them directly. Try to use `DispatcherOperation.Task` as an argument of `Async.AwaitTask`